Quitting Snap Store via Terminal shows error
snap-store --quit
The above code shows me the below error:
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/run/user/0’: Permission denied
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.locale” has path “/system/locale/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy” has path “/system/proxy/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.http” has path “/system/proxy/http/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.https” has path “/system/proxy/https/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp” has path “/system/proxy/ftp/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.socks” has path “/system/proxy/socks/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
09:44:43:0956 GLib-GIO g_app_info_get_name: assertion 'G_IS_APP_INFO (appinfo)' failed
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
09:44:43:0966 Gtk cannot open display: :0

Why these errors appear and how to solve these?
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS 64-bit.
